# How to create fucntion read and post binary file like PostMan which NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, axios, binary, postman

How can I create a function to read binary of file and post it through axios in NodeJS like Postman? I try `fs.readFileSync` but it can't read large file (> 2GB). Please help me explain how does Postman work. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)

Comment: and how can i put it in axios?

Comment: You can do `axios.post(url, fs.createReadStream('foo'))`. It works but it keeps all data until it finish which mean it uses a lot of memory. See [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/961#issuecomment-602795649) and [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/553#issuecomment-628536119).

Comment: I would suggest to use [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#streams) instead. You can do `fs.createReadStream('foo').pipe(got.stream.post(url))`